# How to call an activity from ListView Adapter?

Tags: android

I have custom `ListView`,my `ListView` contains one `button`, if we click on button i want to go another activity with some data.I used following code,

```
holder.mMore.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN){
                  Intent moreIntent=new Intent(getContext(),SelectItemDesp.class);
                  v.getContext().startActivity(moreIntent);

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

it is showing error.pls help me

Comment: Please, could you attach the logcat error? And a suggestion: try v.getContext() insted of getContext() when you are creating the new intent.

Comment: Hi Kameny thanks for reply,Intent moreIntent=new Intent(getContext(),SelectItemDesp.class) here "getContext" showing error

Comment: if (event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN){
              Intent moreIntent=new Intent(yourActivityName.this,SelectItemDesp.class);
             startActivity(moreIntent);
try this. and let me know what happen..Thanks.

Comment: FirstActicity.this is showing error

Comment: just put your whole code in which you have a listview's adapter class.

Comment: Please coud you copy the whole class, this code segment not enough for us to help you. If I clearly understand you cretes your own listadapter and this method is inside the adapter, if it's true, you need to create a Context mContext instance variable and set insede the constructor, and use this variable to create the new activity but it is a suggestion too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you have written a class for your ListView adapter. Let's just name this class quickly: MyListViewAdapter. And in this class you most probably have a constructor. It could look like this:

```
public MyListViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> myList) {
super (context, R.layout.my_layout, R.id.my_text_view, myList);
```

Now the context is what you need to start a new Activity because a ListView adapter which extends an ArrayAdapter cannot start an Activity because its not derived from the Activity-class. So this is how you start an Activity then:

```
context.startActivity(context, GoToClass.class);
```

Just make sure to add a global but private variable to your code (`private Context context`) and add this to your constructor `this.context = context` and if you create the object you have to put `MyListViewAdapter m = new MyListViewAdapter(CurrentClass.this, myListFullOfStrings);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 Intent moreIntent=new Intent(getContext(),SelectItemDesp.class);
              v.getContext().startActivity(moreIntent);
```

With

```
Intent lObjIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectItemDesp.class);
startActivity(lObjIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Hi Vinayak, thanks for reply   here getApplicationContext() showing error

Comment: Then try using your CurrentClass.this

Comment: What is the error? at least paste the logcat output (Do you know what LogCat is?)

Comment: i am try to call an activity from ListView adapter class.Not for activity

Answer (score 0):

I am also using customlistview and also have one delete button in that listview and i have done something like below and it work for me.
and one thing  my class extends ArrayAdapter


`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

    {
        
ViewHolder holder;`

```
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_mymedicine, null);


        holder.btnDelete = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

then onClick() method i have do

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId()) 
    {
      case R.id.btnDelete:
            getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),DeleteActivity.class));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    
}

}

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking the new activity from an anonymous inner class, anything like `this` would refer to this anonymous class only.

Use `MyClass.this` as Vinayak suggested and if error persists, post the logcat here

Comment: i am try to call an activity from ListView adapter class.Not from activity

Comment: But that listview's adapter isn't hanging in the air, right? its in an activity. I am talking about this activity

Answer (score 0):

Try This. It should Work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SelectItemDesp.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
```