# Navigation from one activity to another from listview adapter class

Tags: android

I have to navigate to another activity on image click in listview item from adapter class.
here is my adapter class:

```
 public class RestaurantAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> rest,location,id;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    Context c;
    public RestaurantAdapter(Activity a,Context context, ArrayList<String> restaurants, ArrayList<String> location2 ,ArrayList<String> restid) {
       activity = a;
        rest=restaurants;
        location=location2;
        id=restid;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      //  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
 c=context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return rest.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);
        vi.setClickable(true);
        vi.setFocusable(true);
        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt);;
        TextView f=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.cur);;
        TextView r=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.resid);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
       text.setText(rest.get(position));
       f.setText(location.get(position));
       r.setText(id.get(position));
       image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent=new Intent(c,UserSettings.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",id.get(position) );
                intent.putExtra("resname", rest.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("location", location.get(position));
                c.startActivity(intent);
          }



        });




        return vi;
    }
```

but it gives me exception on this line

```
c.startActivity(intent);
```

any suggestions??

Comment: post the logcat error report...

Comment: try activity.startActivity(intent);

Comment: What is Context context?

Comment: it gives "source not found exception"

Comment: check if UserSettings activity declared in Manifest

Comment: i've added this as an answer, so it can be accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the activity context instead..

```
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ActivityName.this.startActivity(intent)
```

in your case use

```
 a.startActivity(intent)
```

OR
Check if UserSetting activity is declared in your Manifest..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantAdapter.this, UserSettings.class);

            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510868/how-to-call-an-activity-from-listview-adapter)

```
context.startActivity(context, GoToClass.class);
```